# Display content from two different custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to loop through two different custom post types to find out what should be displayed. In CPT project I want to now the name of the house, in CPT portfolio I want to know the category. If these two are the same, I want a certain content from the project CPT to be shown.

On this page you're on the **single-portfolio.php**.

The code below have two errors (at least) the first one is that all the projects house types (`$houseType`) displays for no reason and the second one is that the content within the second loop doesn't display at all.

So, to try to make this a bit more clear: 
I want to display the name and the city of the project which house type name matches the portfolio category (which is the name of the house type)

```
   $args = array('post_type' => 'project');

   $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

   if( $my_query->have_posts()) while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            $houseType = the_field('hustyp');
           $argsPort = array(
               'post_type' => 'portfolio',
               'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
                       'field' => 'slug', //can be set to ID
                       'terms' => $houseType
                   )));

           $port_query = new WP_Query($argsPort);

           if( $port_query->have_posts()) while ($port_query->have_posts()) : $port_query->the_post(); ?>

                   <tr>
                        <td><?php  the_field('brf')?>/<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('ort')?></a></td>
                   </tr>

               <?php

               endwhile;
            ?>



       <?php

       endwhile;
```

I don't know if the best way to go is by creating an own query or something like that.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Okay, I made some progress and finally realized that `the_field` displays the field and therefor I should use `get_field`. But I still don't know how to compare the two different post types to see if it is a match, and after that display only the matches. I'm thinking that creating an array can be a solution, but don't know how to go forward. As you can see in my new code below.

New code:

```
       $args = array(
       'post_type' => array( 'portfolio', 'project' ));

   $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

   if( $my_query->have_posts()) {
       while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

           //Returns All Term Items for "my_taxonomy"
           $term_list_portfolio = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_category', array("fields" => "all"));

           // Just get the category
           $category = $term_list[0]->name;

           // Get the house type
           $houseType = get_field('hustyp');

           $result = array($term_list[0]->name, get_field('hustyp'));
           print_r($result);

          if($category == $houseType) { ?>
             <tr>
                <td><?php the_field('brf')?><?php the_field('ort') ?>

          <?php }


       endwhile;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset query `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` before second wp_query [reffer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query)